# Linux Mint firewall to manage applications connection

Tags: linux, firewall

I'm looking for a firewall for Linux Mint 17 x64.

It should have these features:

- Having a GUI (not required, but appreciated)
- Allow/Block whole software/applications (e.g. Skype, Steam, etc.)

I have tried [Gufw](http://gufw.org/) and others similar to this one, but they are too much selective for what I need. They allow me to insert some 'Rules' and allow/block a range of ports or a specific `IP:port` address. Most of applications are smart enough to open new ports if the default are blocked.

What I need is a more raw firewall (like [Comodo Firewall](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) for Windows) which can give me the option to block the whole software and not just a combination of `IP:port`.

I tried [Douane](http://douaneapp.com/), but on Mint I've got some issues on the installation, probably missing packages.

Do you know any firewall with these specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way i found a solution that can be helpful.

If you didn't yet, try Leopard Flower.

Just follow the instructions listed here

https://github.com/themighty1/lpfw

Once `make` command goes well, type `sudo ./lpfw` to let your Firewall work. Now you just need to go in the '*gui*' folder (you'll find it in the lpfw directory) and double click *gui.py*.

Now you have your interface and your firewall to manage your appliation. Just start the software you need and "Allow" or "Block" depending on your needs.